# Can you improve this solution to interfacing OpenCV 2.4+ to Zxing 1D barcode reader

Tags: opencv, barcode, zxing

I didn't find this solution on the net, had to figure it myself. So, for benefit of others, I'm posing this as a "question":

Can you improve my working interface of OpenCV 2.4+ to the C++ version of Zxing 2.2 1D barcode reader?

Here's my working but perhaps improvable implementation below:

```
/**
 * Gary Bradski, Reading 1D barcodes
 *   License BSD, (c) 2013
 *
 *   Working example of how to call zxing using OpenCV 2.4+ cv::Mat
 *
 * Calling example, this one for 128 barcodes:
 *
 *   Code128Reader cr; //Instantiate a zxing barcode reader, int this case for 128 barcodes, 
 *                     //  but you can use any of their 1D or multi readers here
 *   ... by magic, I find, rectify and islotate a barcode into cv::Mat barcodeImage
 *   decode_image(&cr, barcodeImage);  //Decode the isolated rectified barcode or fail
 *
 */

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//////////////ZXING BARCODE READER//////////////////////////////////////////
#include <zxing/LuminanceSource.h>
#include <zxing/MultiFormatReader.h>
#include <zxing/oned/OneDReader.h>
#include <zxing/oned/EAN8Reader.h>
#include <zxing/oned/EAN13Reader.h>
#include <zxing/oned/Code128Reader.h>
#include <zxing/datamatrix/DataMatrixReader.h>
#include <zxing/qrcode/QRCodeReader.h>
#include <zxing/aztec/AztecReader.h>
#include <zxing/common/GlobalHistogramBinarizer.h>
#include <zxing/Exception.h>

using namespace zxing;
using namespace oned;
using namespace datamatrix;
using namespace qrcode;
using namespace aztec;

class OpenCVBitmapSource : public LuminanceSource
{
private:
    cv::Mat m_pImage;

public:
    OpenCVBitmapSource(cv::Mat &image)
    : LuminanceSource(image.cols, image.rows)
    {
        m_pImage = image.clone();
    }

    ~OpenCVBitmapSource(){}

    int getWidth() const { return m_pImage.cols; }    
    int getHeight() const { return m_pImage.rows; }

    ArrayRef<char> getRow(int y, ArrayRef<char> row) const //See Zxing Array.h for ArrayRef def
    {
        int width_ = getWidth();
        if (!row)
            row = ArrayRef<char>(width_);
        const char *p = m_pImage.ptr<char>(y);
        for(int x = 0; x<width_; ++x, ++p)
            row[x] = *p;
        return row;
    }

    ArrayRef<char> getMatrix() const
    {
        int width_ = getWidth();
        int height_ =  getHeight();
        ArrayRef<char> matrix = ArrayRef<char>(width_*height_);
        for (int y = 0; y < height_; ++y)
        {
            const char *p = m_pImage.ptr<char>(y);
            int yoffset = y*width_;
            for(int x = 0; x < width_; ++x, ++p)
            {
                matrix[yoffset + x] = *p;
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
    /*
    // The following methods are not supported by this demo (the DataMatrix Reader doesn't call these methods)
    bool isCropSupported() const { return false; }
    Ref<LuminanceSource> crop(int left, int top, int width, int height) {}
    bool isRotateSupported() const { return false; }
    Ref<LuminanceSource> rotateCounterClockwise() {}
    */
};

void decode_image(Reader *reader, cv::Mat &image)
{
    try
    {
        Ref<OpenCVBitmapSource> source(new OpenCVBitmapSource(image));
        Ref<Binarizer> binarizer(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(source));
        Ref<BinaryBitmap> bitmap(new BinaryBitmap(binarizer));
        Ref<Result> result(reader->decode(bitmap, DecodeHints(DecodeHints::TRYHARDER_HINT)));//+DecodeHints::DEFAULT_HINT)));
        cout << result->getText()->getText() << endl;
            //Export the read barcode here
    }
    catch (zxing::Exception& e)
    {
            //Export your failure to read the code here
        cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

---

Forgot to attribute what I started with. There is an out of date (will not compile) implementation using IplImages here: 
http://www.idealsoftware.com/opensource/scan-1d-2d-barcodes-webcam-zxing-opencv-visual-c.html

This updates that solution so that it works with Zxing 2.2 and OpenCV 2.1+

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think you can avoid the matrix copy by replacing

```
Ref<OpenCVBitmapSource> source(new OpenCVBitmapSource(image));
```

With

```
Ref<LuminanceSource> source(new GreyscaleLuminanceSource(image.data, image.step, image.rows, 0, 0, image.cols, image.rows));
```

Comment: Perhaps. I'm starting to think there needs to be a deeper port so that OpenCV is used throughout. I hate scattered allocations, I like them all out front at once. I also don't like gluing the detector into the reader. I pass it a detected rectified image. I'd like to be able to modularly improve that part. The reader is "meh", on a challenging set, it gets about 50%. I think it could get maybe 80% by eye.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "deeper". Essentially, the role that OpenCV is playing here is just a data structure wrapped around raw char buffer. `Ref<LuminanceSource> source(new GreyscaleLuminanceSource(image.data, image.step, image.rows, 0, 0, image.cols, image.rows));` simply converts cv::Mat to ZXing preferred data structure with only very small memory allocation. You can still pass in a ROI if you want to use your own detect region.

Comment: Not shown here is my 1D barcode detector, all in a few lines of OpenCV that finds all instances of barcodes in a quite challenging dataset (systematic variations from frontal parallel to more than 60 degree perspective + rotation). I now see an even better way of doing that were you can just reason over polygons. Therefore, I'd like a better separation of detector and reader. For the reader, I'd want to add methods that just reason over polygons and then one that uses pattern recognition (Gallo & Manduchi) that can read patterns even when some of the zero crossings are lost.

Comment: Thank to cxyzs7, this is much clearer than what idealsoftware.com used. But directly providing the pointer didn't worked for me (v 2.4.8). I had to provide an ArrayRef:
GreyscaleLuminanceSource( ArrayRef<char>( ( char * )image.data, image.step * image.rows ), image.step, image.rows, 0, 0, image.cols, image.rows ). Tanks for advice.